# How to get coherence for specific frequency band

Tags: python, scipy

using python `scipy.signal.coherence` I get an array of sample frequencies and an array of corresponding coherence to these frequencies.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.coherence.html

Now, what I do if I want just one value of coherence for a specific frequency band? Do I simply average corresponding values from coherence array or is it more complicated?

Thanks for any comments on this!

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself, yes it's that simple. The average value of coherence from a specific range (selected frequency) does the job.